# Autofac composite pattern

Tags: c#, autofac

I noticed I quite often need to implement composite pattern. For example:

```
interface IService { ... }
class Service1 : IService { ... }
class Service2 : IService { ... }
class CompositeService : IService
{
    public CompositeService(IEnumerable<IService> services) { ... }
    ...
}
```

I want to register CompositeService as IService in container and have dependencies injected.

(looks somewhat similar to Decorator but decorating set of services instead of only one)

What's the best way to do it in autofac?

How would ideal solution look like (for C#)?

**Update:**

My current registration is:

```
builder.RegisterType<Service1>().Named<IService>("impl");
builder.RegisterType<Service2>().Named<IService>("impl");

builder.Register(c => new CompositeService(c.Resolve<IEnumerable<IService>>("impl")))
    .As<IService>();
```

It is similar to *Decorators by Hand* in http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/decorator-support-in-autofac-2-4

Can it be improved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't implemented this or even thought it through fully, but the best syntax I could achieve is:

```
builder
.RegisterComposite<IService>((c, elements) => new CompositeService(elements))
.WithElementsNamed("impl");
```

The `elements` parameter to the registration function would be of type `IEnumerable<IService>` and encapsulate the `c.Resolve<IEnumerable<IService>>("impl")`.

Now how to write it...

Comment: I would also propose a simpler version for simple cases:
`builder.RegisterCompositeType<IService, CompositeService>("impl")`. I just don't like calling constructor manually because dependencies can be injected already.

Comment: @Konstantin Spirin: I had considered putting in that overload but wanted to be explicit about what's going on in my answer. The only thing I would change is that I would still use the `WithElementsNamed` (and also `WithElementsKeyed`) methods, so we wouldn't have to create overloads of `RegisterComposite` for the various registration types (which is something none of the other registration methods do for named/keyed types).

Answer (score 1):

You could try named or keyed registrations. A named registration simply gets a string name, to differentiate it from other registrations of the same interface. Similarly, a key uses some value type, for instance an enum, to discriminate between multiple registrations. Your CompositeService would likely be the default reference, registered by type with no other special info needed. You'll need some method to resolve the other IService dependencies and pass them to the constructor; a factory method for CompositeService may work.

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently doing exactly what you've described. I was hoping for a smarter and shorter code.

Answer (score 1):

Composite registration [will be coming in AutoFac 6.0](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/pull/1152).

It won't automatically create a composite for you, but it will

- inject all other implementations of the interface into the composite
- register the composite as the default interface implementation
- not resolve the composite in `IEnumerable<Interface>` resolutions.