# Nested registration with Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

Im trying to register a class as a specific interface and use explicit classes as paramerters to its constructor. The problem is they all implements the same interface which with my current registration ends up in a Autofac "Circular component dependency detected".

Here is what I got:

```
public interface IWorker
{
    void DoWork();
}
public class FirstLineWorker : IWorker
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        //Do some work
    }
}
public class SecondLineWorker : IWorker
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        //Do some morework
    }
}
public class SequentialWorker : IWorker
{
    private readonly IList<IWorker> _workers;

    public SequentialWorker(params IWorker[] workers)
    {
        _workers = workers;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        foreach (var worker in _workers)
        {
            worker.DoWork();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I in Autofac programmatically register **SequentialWorker** as *IWorker* with explicit parameters **FirstLineWorker** and **SecondLineWorker**?

First attempt which ended up in circular reigstration was:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder
    .RegisterType<FirstLineWorker>()
    .Named<IWorker>(typeof(FirstLineWorker).Name)
    .InstancePerDependency();
builder
    .RegisterType<SecondLineWorker>()
    .Named<IWorker>(typeof(SecondLineWorker).Name)
    .InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<SequentialWorker>()
    .As<IWorker>()
    .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IWorker>(typeof(FirstLineWorker).Name))
    .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IWorker>(typeof(SecondLineWorker).Name))
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 approaches available for you. First, create a new, empty interface, derived from `IWorker`, like

```
public interface IWorkExecutor : IWorker { }
```

Then, register "normal" workers as `IWorker`, and "executor" as `IWorkExecutor`

```
builder.RegisterType<Worker1>().As<IWorker>();
builder.RegisterType<Worker2>().As<IWorker>();
builder.RegisterType<SequentialWorker>().As<IWorkExecutor>();
```

Second approach would be quite similar to the code you already have:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<Worker1>().Named<IWorker>(nameof(Worker1));
containerBuilder.RegisterType<Worker2>().Named<IWorker>(nameof(Worker2));
containerBuilder.RegisterType<SequentialWorker>().As<IWorker>()
    .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
        (pi, cc) => pi.Name == "workers",
        (pi, cc) => new [] { cc.ResolveNamed<IWorker>(nameof(Worker1)), cc.ResolveNamed<IWorker>(nameof(Worker2)) }));
```

You have to pass single array parameter for `params IWorker[] workers` in `SequentialWorker`.

BTW `InstancePerDependency()` is not actually needed, as this is the default lifetime scope when registering types.

Comment: IMHO the first approach is better - it's cleaner and more readable. Also, in fact the role of Worker1 and Worker2 is slighlty different than SequentialWorker, even when they have the same interface

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in part by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092602/autofac-composite-pattern) question on the composite pattern (which is what you are implementing here).

The solution is to register all the services with a common name and resolve the named collection within the registration for the composite:

```
builder
    .RegisterType<FirstLineWorker>()
    .Named<IWorker>("worker")
    .InstancePerDependency();
builder
    .RegisterType<SecondLineWorker>()
    .Named<IWorker>("worker")
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

and either

```
builder
    .Register<IWorker>(c => new SequentialWorker(
            c.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<IWorker>>("worker").ToArray()))
    .As<IWorker>()
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

or

```
builder.RegisterType<SequentialWorker>()
    .As<IWorker>()
    .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
        (pi, cc) => pi.Name == "workers",
        (pi, cc) => cc.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<IWorker>>("worker").ToArray()));
```

it's also worth mentioning that `params` is not really required, you can use `IEnumerable` as it avoids the need to execute `ToArray()` when resolving the `"worker"`'s

```
public SequentialWorker(IEnumerable<IWorker> workers)
{
    _workers = workers;
}
```